# Extract SNMP community string on Windows XP

Tags: windows, service, snmp

I need to script a way to determine the SNMP community string on Windows XP hosts. Basically the command line equivalent to the GUI to examine the SNMP Service Properties.

I thought it may be in the registry, but even though community strings are commonly listed, those are not the actual string set by the GUI.

I'm looking for preferably an existing command line method, or ihow to code it. My task is to add a command to an script that runs periodically verifying a bunch of system configuration items, and now I need to add this as well.